# python abstractmethod with another baseclass breaks abstract functionality

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, metaclass, abstract-methods

Consider the following code example

```py
import abc
class ABCtest(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        raise RuntimeError("Abstract method was called, this should be impossible")

class ABCtest_B(ABCtest):
    pass

test = ABCtest_B()
```

This correctly raises the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../test.py", line 10, in <module>
    test = ABCtest_B()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ABCtest_B with abstract methods foo
```

However when the subclass of `ABCtest` also inherits from a built in type like `str` or `list` there is no error and `test.foo()` calls the abstract method:

```
class ABCtest_C(ABCtest, str):
    pass

>>> test = ABCtest_C()
>>> test.foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    test.foo()
  File "/.../test.py", line 5, in foo
    raise RuntimeError("Abstract method was called, this should be impossible")
RuntimeError: Abstract method was called, this should be impossible
```

This seems to happen when inheriting from any class defined in C including `itertools.chain` and `numpy.ndarray` but still correctly raises errors with classes defined in python. Why would implementing one of a built in types break the functionality of abstract classes?

Comment: @DonkeyKong (or anyone else who doesn't get it) the method `foo` should be enforced to be overridden in a subclass, normally (and without also inheritting from `str`) instantiating it raises an error, however when also inherriting from `str` no error happens and the abstract method `test.foo` is a valid callable method.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Just caught on, thanks :)

Comment: @Torxed `str` isn't a variable name.

Comment: I just realized, thanks for making me read it twice @DonkeyKong :)

Comment: considering the error that is normally raised is definitely not raised from `abc.py` since there is no entry in the traceback I think that the error originates from `type.__call__` so I think a look into the C source code will be required to answer why this is happening...

Comment: oh heck - well if anyone is into the source, I'd be delighted. But is this part of a specification? could there be a situation where this behaviour is desired? or is it a bug, or simply case that has not been regarded?

Answer (score 15):

Surprisingly, the test that prevents instantiating abstract classes happens in [`object.__new__`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/typeobject.c#l3391), rather than anything defined by the `abc` module itself:

```
static PyObject *
object_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    ...
    if (type->tp_flags & Py_TPFLAGS_IS_ABSTRACT) {
        ...
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "Can't instantiate abstract class %s "
                     "with abstract methods %U",
                     type->tp_name,
                     joined);
```

(Almost?) all built-in types that aren't `object` supply a different `__new__` that overrides `object.__new__` *and does not call `object.__new__`*. When you multiple-inherit from a non-`object` built-in type, you inherit its `__new__` method, bypassing the abstract method check.

I don't see anything about `__new__` or multiple inheritance from built-in types in the `abc` documentation. The documentation could use enhancement here.

It seems kind of strange that they'd use a metaclass for the ABC implementation, making it a mess to use other metaclasses with abstract classes, and then put the crucial check in core language code that has nothing to do with `abc` and runs for both abstract and non-abstract classes.

There's a [report](https://bugs.python.org/issue5996) for this issue on the issue tracker that's been languishing since 2009.

Answer (score 5):

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60015859/5814701) and based on [user2357112 supports Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica)s linked bug report, I came up with this workaround (based on the suggestion from [Xiang Zhang](https://bugs.python.org/issue5996#msg266704)):

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Base(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        pass

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        abstractmethods = getattr(cls, '__abstractmethods__', None)
        if abstractmethods:
            msg = "Can't instantiate abstract class {name} with abstract method{suffix} {methods}"
            suffix = 's' if len(abstractmethods) > 1 else ''
            raise TypeError(msg.format(name=cls.__name__, suffix=suffix, methods=', '.join(abstractmethods)))
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

class Derived(Base, tuple):
    pass

Derived()
```

This raises `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Derived with abstract methods bar, foo`, which is the original behaviour.