# Python abstract base classes and multiple inheritance

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, numpy-ndarray, abc

I am trying to create a python (3.5) class structure where I use abstract methods to indicate which methods should be implemented. The following works as expected:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class Base(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

class Derived(Base, object):
    # Inheriting from object probably is superfluous (?)
    pass

Derived()  # throws a TypeError
```

When I add a class to `Derived`, it does not work anymore. Here shown with a `tuple` (in my specific case I want to use a `np.ndarray`):

```py
class Base(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

class Derived(Base, tuple):
    pass

Derived()  # does not throw an error
```

Are abstract base classes in python not intended for multiple inheritance? Of course I could add old-school `NotImplementedError`s, but then an error is only thrown when the method is called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python abstractmethod with another baseclass breaks abstract functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398966/python-abstractmethod-with-another-baseclass-breaks-abstract-functionality)

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. I guess the only solutions for the moment are a modified `__new__` or the NotImplementedError workaround.

Comment: no problem. This was a super interesting edge case. I spent 30 min trying to figure out how to handle this problem and couldn't figure out a clean solution. Did you come up with something clean?

Comment: Sure, since this question is locked as a duplicate, I posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60125441/5814701).