# Is there such a thing as an AbstractSubClass in python?

Tags: python, abstract-class

#### The background

In python, if you were defining an Abstract Base Class which requires that its methods be overwritten, you'd do:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class MyAbstractClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def my_method(self):
        pass
```

The following code would then fail because it doesn't implement `my_method`.

```
class MyConcreteClass(MyAbstractClass):
    pass
```

But **what if I want to define the method requirements of a mixin class**?

```
class MyMixin:

    def my_mixin_method(self):
        self.a_required_method()
```

The following code is then valid:

```
class MyBase:
    def a_required_method(self):
        pass

class MyFull(MyMixin, MyBase):
    pass
```

The following code is also valid...

```
class MyDubious(MyMixin):
    pass
```

But exposes an error at runtime:

```
MyFull().my_mixin_method() # Works
MyDubious().my_mixin_method()  # Runtime error
```

#### The Question

Is there something like `AbstractBaseClass` which can be added to Mixin classes, to ensure that a derived class can't be instantiated unless it inherits correctly?

I'm thinking a nice API would look like:

```
from asc import ASC, requiredmethod

class MyRobustMixin(ASC):
    @requiredmethod
    def a_required_method(self):
        pass

    def my_mixin_method(self):
        self.a_required_method()
```

Comment: A related question with a similar usage pattern (not quite the same but of close interest): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398966/python-abstractmethod-with-another-baseclass-breaks-abstract-functionality